# Batch File to Duplicate column in CSV file

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I need to be able to take a column in a CSV file and duplicate it so that the same exact values are on and end of each file.

See the example below which shows the input and desired output.

Input

```
abc,123,tim,cook
xyz,456,steve,jobs
```

Desired output

```
abc,123,tim,cook,123
xyz,456,steve,jobs,456
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this with a batch script

Any ideas?

Comment: `FOR /F` will be perfect

Comment: So you want to append the second CSV column  to the end of the entries? Or do you want to append it after every entry?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean the difference to be between those two things, but I want to add the second entry of each row added to the end of that same row.

Comment: What about the header? I would suggest that a CSV, with a duplicate header field is malformed, or could create issues.

Comment: @Compo is correct with the header statement, I added an additional script for the purpose to append a new header column, if it is relevant. If for instance your csv file is read by a sql query for instance that uses headers as identifiers, it will cause issues as there are 2 columns which are identical if you use the first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example file `test.csv`

```
@echo off
(for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,* delims=," %%i in ("test.csv") do (
    echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%j
 )
)>new.csv
```

Real simple, we take the string and assign to metaviariable `%%i` then we split the string by `,` and use token 2 only, we then echo the metavariable `%%i` and append `%%a` to it with a comma. The output will then be in `new.csv`

PS!! As @Compo stated in a comment, having duplicate header values could create issues, depending on what you do with the file, in that case, you can spesify a new header field, which is not duplicate and simpply append the field to the header, just make sure to change the value `New_HeaderValue` to the actual new header value.:

```
@echo off
(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("test.csv") do echo %%i,New_HeaderValue & goto :remainder)>new.csv
:remainder
(for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2,* delims=," %%i in ("test.csv") do (
    echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%j
 )
)>>new.csv
```

Comment: Why two nested `for` loops? `for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2,* delims=," %%i in ("test.csv")  do echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%i`

Comment: @Stephan shouldn’t be `... echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%j`?

Comment: @Stephan, Let's just say I played it safe, I posted from mobile without testing. I will amend answer when I am on my laptop again. Thanks

Comment: @elzooilogico: yes - typo.

Comment: @Stephan, sorted now!